# How to insert a compatible unique pointer to a vector?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

For example, I have two classes `A` and `B`. `B` is derived from `A`.

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
```

I have a vector of unique pointer of `A` and I can push back a unique pointer to the vector.

```
vector<unique_ptr<A>> vA;
unique_ptr<A> a(new A);
vA.push_back(std::move(a));
```

(1) How to push back a unique pointer of `B`?

```
vector<unique_ptr<A>> vA;
unique_ptr<B> b(new B);
vA.push_back(std::move(b)); //?
```

(2) If the vector is for `B`, how to push back a unique pointer of `A` (assuming it is down casted)

```
vector<unique_ptr<B>> vB;
unique_ptr<A> a(new B);
vB.push_back(std::move(a)); //?
```

Comment: Have you tried any of this? What problems did you encounter? What aspects of the problem did you not understand?

Comment: What goes wrong when you try (1) ? Also: There is no downcast in your example (2)?

Comment: It's not suitable to use `std::move`. It's usually used with move constructors.

Comment: @vbmaster Umm, what? It's perfectly OK (even required) to `std::move()` a `std::unique_ptr` to get it into a container.

Comment: @KerrekSB (1) is okay. For (2) I try `vB.push_back((unique_ptr<B>&&)std::move(a))`. Not sure if this is the right way?

Comment: @user1899020: There's no "right way" to store base-class pointers in a container of derived-class pointers; but that cast is definitely wrong, since it gives undefined behaviour whether or not the pointer `a` actually points to a `B`.

Comment: @Angew OK... I understand.. it is smart pointer

Comment: Well, (2) doesn't make sense, just as it doesn't make sense for plain pointers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (1) How to push back a unique pointer of `B`?

Exactly as you're doing it. Doesn't that work for you? If not, what error do you get?

> (2) If the vector is for `B`, how to push back a unique pointer of `A`

Usually you shouldn't, since there's no way to tell whether the the pointer actually points to a `B`. If you really know what you're doing, then something horrible like

```
vB.push_back(unique_ptr<B>(static_cast<B*>(a.release())));
```

should do what you want. For polymorphic types, you could use `dynamic_cast` (taking care not to leak the object if the conversion fails) to make that safer.

Comment: @DieterLücking: It's not lost (and certainly not loosed), just temporarily released. Nothing can throw before it's reassigned to a new `unique_ptr`. I don't think there's any way to achieve the desired conversion if you also require it to be owned by a `unique_ptr` at every instant during the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

1)

You can use

```
unique_ptr<A> b(new B);
vA.push_back(std::move(b));
```

to insert a pointer to B into the vector.

2)

I'm not 100% sure on this one, but if it's a safe downcast, you may be able to do

```
unique_ptr<B> a(dynamic_cast<B*>(new A));
vB.push_back(std::move(a));
```

The important thing to notice is that the types match up. If you have a vector of `unique_ptr<A>`, you need to pass in `unique_ptr<A>` values. You can however constructor a `unique_ptr<A>` from a pointer to B, as I've done in 1). Hope this helps a little.

Comment: You cannot do `unique_ptr<B> a(new A)` as that would require an implicit downcast.  You would have to make the cast explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, I added an explicit dynamic_cast.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` won't work here, since the types aren't polymorphic. Even if they were, you'd have a memory leak if the conversion fails.